# SQL record entries, different test cases

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

a little question about C# stored procedures...and SQL DB in general:
 When you are passing a variable value from C# to a stored procedure, at times you have

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1 name, column2 name, column3 name, columnN name) 
VALUES (@the actual values1, @values2, @valueN);
```

other times you dont have the column names but only the VALUES being entered...
what would happen if I typed something like this, (assume table has 3 columns called "bob", "ash", and "will"):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (bob, will) VALUES ("hi","hello");
 OR 
INSERT INTO tablename (bob, will) VALUES ("hi","hello","okay"); 
OR 
INSERT INTO tablename (bob, will) VALUES ("hello");
```

how will it affect the entry?

Comment: Please format your question to make it readble.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The way your stored proc is defined determines how you should program the call to it from C#. Maybe you should post your stored proc to see how it can be called.

Comment: If you don't know what fields your data is going into, then you are doing something very wrong. How would you know if the value 'hello' beonged to Bob, will or ash? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First query insert that record correctly (if there are no primary keys violations).
Second query fails because you have three values and two fields.
Third query fails because you have one value for two fields.

Comment: The third query would not parse too.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I cannot try, but ok, if you tell me I edit my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: The first might not work either if the third field in the table does not allow nulls.

Answer (score 1):

The first query would insert default value into `ash`, the other two would not parse.

Answer (score 1):

As Quassnoi and Marco pointed out the the error concern with sql side.

While debugging in C# you will get following error.

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must
>   match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL first query gets executed successfully whereas for the second query u'll get the following error : 
There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.
and third query will also produce following error :
There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.